# Removing only sequential duplicate XML elements in C#

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

So I have a list of XML Elements that I wish to go through and remove duplicate elements. As the loop progresses, if a duplicate is found between current index and index+1 then index+1 needs to be removed and next value which should be compared against index should be index+2 and so on until there are no duplicates in a sequence. If index+3 is not a duplicate compared to index then the loop should carry on as normal scouting for sequential dupes.

```
<Update>
  <Properties id="42" rotation="0.00 0.00 -0.01" />
</Update>

<Update>
  <Properties id="42" rotation="0.00 0.00 -0.01" />
</Update>

<Update>
  <Properties id="42" rotation="0.00 0.00 -0.01" />
</Update>

<Update>
  <Properties id="42" rotation="2.42 2.24 -4.42" />
</Update>
```

I am currently using LinQ to manipulate the XDocument elements. Currently I am using an If statement to compare index against index+1 and if they are the same then I remove index+1. When i++; then index now is at position which had the attribute previously removed hence if the next index+1 now contains the same value as index - 2 (because we increased it by 1 on next iteration), the sequential duplicate is not registered. Current output:

```cs
if (xmlElementList.Count() > 1) {

  // Start looping through all modifications
  for (int i = 0; i < xmlElementList.Count() - 1; i++) {
    var currEl = xmlElementList.ElementAt(i).Element("Properties");
    var nextEl = xmlElementList.ElementAt(i+1).Element("Properties");

    // Check for duplicate rotation attributes
    if (currEl.Attribute("rotation") != null) {
      if (currEl.Attribute("rotation ").Value ==
      nextEl.Attribute("rotation ").Value) {

        nextEl.Attribute("rotation ").Remove();
      }
    }
  }              
}
```

```
<Update>
    <Properties id="42" rotation="0.00 0.00 -0.01" />
  </Update>
  <Update>
    <Properties id="42" />
  </Update>
  <Update>
    <Properties id="42" rotation="0.00 0.00 -0.01" />
  </Update>
<Update>
    <Properties id="42" rotation="2.42 2.24 -4.42" />
  </Update>
```

There should be not be two duplicates in a sequence. If there are duplicates in the file itself that is fine but index+1 should not contain the same value as index. Expected output:

```
<Update>
  <Properties id="42" rotation="0.00 0.00 -0.01" />
</Update>

<Update>
  <Properties id="42" />
</Update>

<Update>
  <Properties id="42" />
</Update>

<Update>
  <Properties id="42" rotation="2.42 2.24 -4.42" />
</Update>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your current approach is that you're advancing which element you're looking at too soon. At the first occurrence of a match, you should be comparing the original first item, to the next after. You're only looking at adjacent items.

You can craft an xpath query that could select `<Update>` elements that have the same id and rotation as the previous pretty easily.

```
//Update[preceding-sibling::Update/Properties/@id      =Properties/@id
     and preceding-sibling::Update/Properties/@rotation=Properties/@rotation]
```

Then alter these elements as needed.

```
var xpath = "//Update[preceding-sibling::Update/Properties/@id=Properties/@id and preceding-sibling::Update/Properties/@rotation=Properties/@rotation]";
var fixUpdates = doc.XPathSelectElements(xpath);
var fixProperties = fixUpdates.Elements("Properties");
var removeMe = fixProperties.Attributes("rotation");
removeMe.Remove();
```